# Open custom property Show Details from code in VSTO add-in

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

With SharePoint you can set metadata properties on documents. These properties can be set in Word, Excel and PowerPoint. Before Office 2016 this was possible through a Document Information Panel. However, since 2016 the only way to set this data is from File -> Info. There you get a list of all the metadata. If the metadata is a custom property field, it will display Show Details instead of the value. If you click on Show Details a dialog window will open and show all the metadata about the document. This results in a lot of mouseclicks for the user and I wonder if it is possible to write an VSTO add-in where I from code can open this Show Details dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you show the Document Information Panel in VBA:

```
Dim app As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

Set app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
app.Visible = True
Set doc = app.Documents.Add

app.DisplayDocumentInformationPanel = True
```

In c#, given you are already in the document it would be:

```
ActiveDocument.Application.DisplayDocumentInformationPanel = true;
```

That should do it, if you need/mean something else let us know

Comment: And you have tried this in Office 2016? From what I understand the Document Information Panel is removed in Office 2016...

Comment: I actually tried it in Office 2016 and found the floating dialog to be more friendly :-) Sadly I missed the fact that the properties you needed are not in there. Apparently a big miss, vote (I did) here to at least bring back the developer option to access the information: https://word.uservoice.com/forums/304924-word-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/9748581-missing-document-panel-in-word-2016 It has already over two hundred votes and is under review by the Word team. Existing solutions appear to be currently in trouble though ...